# The named parameter 'desiredAccuracy' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart, geofencing

```
static startGeofenceService(
      {required String? pointedLatitude,
        required String? pointedLongitude,
        required String? radiusMeter,
        int? eventPeriodInSeconds}) {
    //parsing the values to double if in any case they are coming in int etc
    double latitude = _parser(pointedLatitude);
    double longitude = _parser(pointedLongitude);
    double radiusInMeter = _parser(radiusMeter);
    //starting the geofence service only if the positionstream is null with us
    if (_positionStream == null) {
      _geoFencestream = _controller.stream;
      _positionStream = Geolocator.getPositionStream(
        desiredAccuracy //here the error: LocationAccuracy.high,
      ).listen((Position position) {
        double distanceInMeters = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
            latitude, longitude, position.latitude, position.longitude);
        _printOnConsole(
            latitude, longitude, position, distanceInMeters, radiusInMeter);
        _checkGeofence(distanceInMeters, radiusInMeter);
        _positionStream!
            .pause(Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: eventPeriodInSeconds!)));
      });
      _controller.add(GeofenceStatus.init);
    }
  }
```

I have no idea why the 'desiredAccuracy' part gets error. I think the code is correct right? Please send me help how to figure out that issue

Answer (score 1):

To make your code work,

Declare a variable `locationSettings` first like this

```
final LocationSettings locationSettings = LocationSettings(
  accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
  distanceFilter: 100,
double latitude = _parser(pointedLatitude);
double longitude = _parser(pointedLongitude);
double radiusInMeter = _parser(radiusMeter);
);
```

Then modify `getPositionStream` like in the snippet below

```
 _positionStream = Geolocator.getPositionStream(
       locationSettings: locationSettings
      ).listen((Position position) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`desiredAccuracy` is a parameter of `Geolocator.getCurrentPosition()`. You are using `Geolocator.getPositionStream()`. This method doesn't have that parameter. I'd suggest looking at the package's documentation to see how to use that method: https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

Comment: but i already declare the Geolocator.getCurrentPosition() at another dart file. and the coded there should use Geolocator.getPositionStream() not Geolocator.getCurrentPosition() . Then what should i do?

Comment: @peanut the linked website shows examples of how to use `getPositionStream`

Comment: sorry but i don't understand how to fix the coding. I already read the example. To be honest i'm still beginner my bad :(